# Simple php header redirect not working in add on domain

Tags: php, header

I am using a very simple header redirect:

```
<?php header('Location: http://www.example.com'); ?>
```

I am using this in an add-on domain so the directory structure looks like this:

```
/home/username/public_html/addondomain.com/goto/directory/redirect.php
```

It doesn't work when I have it in this directory, but it does work in a different directory in my main account.  For example:

```
/home/username/public_html/recommends/redirect.php
```

It would seem to be a problem with the directory permissions, but everything seems to be fine.  Is this possibly a problem with the add on domain?

This is probably something really simple, but I just can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Barry

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? You get a 404 error? the script fails to redirect? Redirects to the wrong place?

Comment: Sorry.  It redirects to the wrong place.  It redirects to the index page of the add on domain rather than the external link.

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess with RewriteRules in the "addondomain.com"-directory?

Comment: No.  The only .htaccess file is in the document root.  Should I have one in the add on domain as well?

Comment: If you replace the header() with phpinfo(), do you get the PHP info page? As you've stated this only happens with subdomains, it may well be some weirdness with how the subdomain is set up - or the filesystem location may not match where the server is looking for files.

Comment: And in any of the subdirectories of "addondomain.com"? Because the redirect to the index might come from a RewriteRule or some other redirect-statement in a .htaccess.

Comment: What's the documentroot of example.com set to? An absolute url in a redirect like that isn't going to just move you around within one site's directory tree.

Comment: example.com is an external link.  I am using this to create a redirect for an affiliate link.  example.com is not my site.

Comment: @Marc B I am going to change my first answer.  It doesn't redirect at all.  When you enter the URL in your browser it doesn't do anything except show an oddly formatted version of the index page for the subdirectory and the URL remains as it was entered.  So it would look like: http://addondomain.com/goto/directory/redirect.php

Comment: Please see as well [PHP Location Header Causing an Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857858/php-location-header-causing-an-error)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this myself using .htaccess.  Thanks everyone for your comments.

Here is a sample of the code I used:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^goto/directory/([/_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$ link.php?id=directory&id2=$1
</IfModule>
```

This now calls a php file called link.php which looks up the user information from the MySQL database to complete the link.  The link.php file redirects to the newly created link using the header() function.  This way I can have unlimited affiliates creating custom links.